# cocos2d-x how to pause a layer's actions and schedule, and then resume them

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have a scene contains many layer(the layer contains many sprite), how can I pause the schedule and actions , but then I can resume them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use functions:

```
void CCNode::pauseSchedulerAndActions();
void CCNode::resumeSchedulerAndActions();
```

If you want all the layer's children to pause, you need a loop to do do this.

```
CCArray* childs = this->getChildren();
CCObject* child;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(childs, child)
{
   CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)child;
   child -> pauseSchedulerAndActions();
}
```

If you just want a special child to pause;Just use function `getChildByTag` to get the child and pause the sprite's action.

Hope it will be helpful :)

Comment: en, thanks!But there some sprites are running action, use the  'pauseSchedulerAndActions' cannot pause these sprites'action.

Comment: Doesnt work for v4 as these have been removed.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29910037/1133011 worked for me

Answer (score 5):

In cocos2dx 3.2 For pausing actions,add

`Director::getInstance()->pause();` in pause button callback.
and `Director::getInstance()->resume();` to resume.

For pausing physics of a body in Chipmunk add,

```
for (auto nod :this->getChildren()) {

 nod->getPhysicsBody()->setResting(true); 
}
```

and

```
for (auto nod :this->getChildren()) {

 nod->getPhysicsBody()->setResting(false); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**pause:**

pauseSchedulerAndActions();

unscheduleAllSelectors();

**resume:**

resumeSchedulerAndActions();

scheduleUpdate();